# Exclude properties from being listed in Swagger UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

Let say I have the following model

```
public class UserResourceParameters 
{
  public string FirstName { get; set;}
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string FullName { get => FirstName + " " + LastName; }
}
```

And the following controller action

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(UserResourceParameters resourceParameters)
{
  ...
}
```

When I run my apps and go to the swagger interface/UI for above action, it listed all 3 properties as the accepted parameters

1. FirstName
2. LastName
3. FullName

Actually I don't want Swagger to show `FullName` as one of the accepted parameters, as I only want it to be a getters.

How can I tell swagger to show only `FirstName` and `LastName` as the accepted parameters?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is decorate property with annotation `[JsonIgnore]`.

```
public class UserResourceParameters 
{
  public string FirstName { get; set;}
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  [JsonIgnore]
  public string FullName { get => FirstName + " " + LastName; }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. `FullName` is still shown as one of the parameter.

Comment: What tool do you use for swagger schema generation?

Comment: I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Comment: Whatever went wrong for the OP, this answer is correct.

Comment: If this is not working for you, you might need to install the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft` nuget.